# Solving Laplace's equation for semi-infinite bar using conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am trying to solve the 2d version of Laplace's equation ($\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y^2}=0$) for the semi-infinite bar shown below in the shaded region.

[image]

That is for the region bounded by $x= \pm L$ and $y=0,\infty$ given the boundary conditions that $V=0$ for $x=\pm L$ and $V=V_0$ for $y=L$. I know this can be done via separation of variables, but I want to do it via complex analysis and conformal mappings. I know that we can get to:

[image]

Via the mapping $z'=\sin(z)$. But I don't know what further mappings to do to make the problem more simple to solve, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Once you reduced the problem to half-plane, the argument function can be used to produce a harmonic function with any piecewise constant boundary values you want. Specifically, to have $v_0$ on $[a,b]$ and zero value elsewhere, you would use 
$$
h(z) = \frac{v_0}{\pi}(\arg(z-b)-\arg(z-a))
$$
where the argument is understood as taking values in $[0,\pi]$ in the upper half-plane.